# stuck at "redmi" screen after unsuccessfull root

Tags: android, root

i tried to root my phone yesterday (redmi note 8 pro) and everything was going great. i was using twrp to do it and i installed magisk-v20.4.zip using that twrp on my phone. then i reeboted the system and i'm stuck. my screen is flashing "redmi" text in the middle and "powered by android" on the bottom, then it turns off and again - "redmi" in the middle and "powered by android" on the bottom. i can only go to fastboot mode and come back, nothing else. rebooting doesn't seem to help. does anyone know how to fix my phone? just make it work, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try booting into download mode, and then if possible find a flash tool to reflash the device

Comment: how do i do it? i mean booting into download mode?

Comment: Swith your phone off, then turn it back on by pressing volume up and power at the same time. https://www.hardreset.info/devices/xiaomi/xiaomi-redmi-note-8-pro/download-mode/ you can refer to this link

Comment: okay, i finally downloaded some (i think) latest begonia from xiaomi website and pasted a disk images folder into the flashboot tool and using file flash_all.bat i finally fixed it :D

Comment: Yep, it's usually the only way to fix it, unless you have the enough know how to patch the broken boot.img